# fitting by linear combination of exponential functions

Tags: numerical-methods, exponential-function, least-squares

Suppose that we have a set of points $(x_1,y_1), \ldots (x_n,y_n)$, and we want to fit a function of the form $f(x) = ae^{2x} + be^x + c$ to those points. If we make $z=e^x$, then our function becomes a second-degree polynomial in $z$: $f(z) = az^2+bz+c$. My question is: Which transformations (if any) do I have to make on the points $(x_i,y_i)$ in order to be able to fit the second-degree polynomial $f(z)$ to the set of transformed points, by the usual method of least squares?

Comment: None, you will have an over-determined set of linear equations in a, b and c when you substitute your x and y values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Least squares folution to overdetermined system $Ax = b$ is given by
$$
x = \left(A^\mathsf{T} A\right)^{-1} A^\mathsf{T} b
$$
There's no need to do a transform $z = e^x$, it is solvable as it is. Rewrite the overdetermined system
$$
e^{2x_1} a + e^{x_1} b + c = f_1\\
e^{2x_2} a + e^{x_2} b + c = f_2\\
\vdots\\
e^{2x_n} a + e^{x_n} b + c = f_n\\
$$
in matrix form
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
e^{2x_1} & e^{x_1} & 1\\
e^{2x_2} & e^{x_2} & 1\\
&\vdots\\
e^{2x_n} & e^{x_n} & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad
f = \begin{pmatrix}
f_1\\f_2\\\vdots\\f_n
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now,
$$
A^\mathsf{T} A = \begin{pmatrix}
\sum_i e^{4x_i}& \sum_i e^{3x_i} & \sum_i e^{2x_i}\\
\sum_i e^{3x_i}& \sum_i e^{2x_i} & \sum_i e^{x_i}\\
\sum_i e^{2x_i}& \sum_i e^{x_i} &1
\end{pmatrix}\\
A^\mathsf{T} b = \begin{pmatrix}
\sum_i e^{2x_i} f_i\\
\sum_i e^{x_i} f_i\\
\sum_i f_i
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Understood, thanks a lot. Now, I suppose that the same holds for approximating a set of points by a rational function of $e^x$, right? I mean, that it can be done exactly as if we were approximating the set of points by a rational function on $x$. Am I correct?

Comment: Only while fitting function stays linear in parameters $a,b,c,\dots$

Comment: You mean that it cannot be done with rational functions of $e^x$ then?

Comment: I mean something like $\frac{ae^{2x}+be^x+c}{de^{2x}+fe^x+g}$

Comment: Yes, but that needs a special transform to make it linear. Like
$$
f_i  =\frac{ae^{2x_i}+be^{x_i}+c}{de^{2x_i}+fe^{x_i}+1}\\
ae^{2x_i}+be^{x_i}+c - f_i (de^{2x_i}+fe^{x_i}) = f_i
$$

Comment: Ah, Ok, thanks again